# BinaryFormatter fails to deserialize the object into the same type

Tags: c#, serialization

I use BinaryFormatter to serialize the object of type that is present in the assembly I dynamically loaded. The idea is to serialize the object, send it over the network and then deserialize it and use it. However I get this error:

> [A]Samples.RecordKeeping.Person cannot be cast to
>   [B]Samples.RecordKeeping.Person. Type A originates from 'Samples,
>   Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context
>   'Default' at location 'C:\Samples.dll'. Type B originates from
>   'Samples, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in
>   the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Temp\Samples.dll'."}

Both the Assemblies are the same. i.e. copied from the same location so they cannot have namespace or other type name issues. Both the assemblies are dynamically loaded into the AppDomain at sending and receiving locations

the class declaration is like this:

```
namespace Samples.RecordKeeping
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
}

    private INodeTask LoadUserCode()
    {
        INodeTask ret = null;

        try
        {
            var type = typeof(AssemblyLoader);
            var loader = (AssemblyLoader) AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName);
            var assembly = loader.GetAssembly(_assembly);
            var filename =Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_assembly);

            foreach (var it in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (string.Compare(it.Name, _class, true) == 0)
                {
                    ret = assembly.CreateInstance(it.FullName, true,
                        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.CreateInstance,
                        null, null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                        null) as INodeTask;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _journal.Error(ex, $"Failed to load assembly {_assembly} for {_class}");
        }

        return ret;
    }



class AssemblyLoader : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public Assembly GetAssembly(string assemblyPath)
    {
        var assembly = (Assembly) null;
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(assemblyPath))
                assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
            else
                throw new FileNotFoundException($"could not find {assemblyPath}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return assembly;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are they dynamically loaded using the same method?

Comment: The serialization and Deserialization happens in the same way, same methods

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the assemblies. Is it possible to know which method is invoked to load them?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not getting your point. You mean which method is used to load assembly dynamically?

Comment: Can you refactor this `Person` into a struct? It would be much easier for you to send it over network.

Comment: @SimpleFellow Yes, it is what I mean

Comment: Why not a class like this. We can use EntityFramework entity objects also. We won't be converting every entity declaration into a struct

Comment: @Matteo Umili  https://codeshare.io/5MNj8n

Comment: Just asking because you're using `BinaryFormatter` which has to sign and read the signature of the assembly during it's serialization/deserialization process. This is much easier using structures. Problem in your case can be with assembly signing because context is different [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594831/binaryformatter-is-it-possible-to-deserialize-known-class-without-the-assembly)

Comment: @SimpleFellow So, if I'm not wrong you load dynamically an `AssemblyLoader` and then you use it to load the assembly containing the `Person` class? How does `AssemblyLoader`'s `GetAssembly` work?

Comment: Check the codeshare again

Comment: @SimpleFellow Thanks, are you really sure that also the serializator use that `GetAssembly` method to load the assembly? I have this doubt because if also it uses the `LoadFrom` method I'd expect the type `A` (the one referred in the exception message) to be in the context `LoadFrom`, not in the context `Default`

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code you use to load the assembly and call the Serializer/Deserializer

Comment: @PhllipH done but no answer